# Nginx 404 Not Found when using a specific URL

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have an angular application that is being built using Docker and deployed on Nginx. Let's assume our website is called "**x**". The website is displayed clearly when going to *x.com*. However, when a 404 not found error is displayed when I go directly to "*x.com/dashboard"*, although I can correctly see it if I navigate from my homepage.

I have tried several options with my nginx default.conf file with no luck. My angular application is a Single Page Application, and I'm making sure that the index.html is being created successfully under var/www/html. Below you can see the current status of my default.conf file

Note that I want the website to show the root index.html for any path. For example, it should show the homepage in case of x.com or x.com/dashboard

```
server {

  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /var/www/html;

  location / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to solve it using `useHash: true` in the routing config.